# "Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test" testing custom hook which uses useEffect and useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I'm currently trying to successfully test a custom hook which makes use of an `useEffect` and `useReducer` hooks. The custom hook is supposed to return an array of objects from the request made inside the `useEffect` hook where it dispatches a value against the reducer based on the request result. It already works for my purposes but I'm still coming across this common warning in my tests when the hook runs the `dispatch` part. I have no way of wrapping this inside an `act` so is there any way around?

The custom hook:

```
export const useJobs = () => {
  const [jobs, dispatch] = useReducer(httpReducer<JobHome[]>(), null);
  const httpService = useContext(HttpContext);

  const numberOfResults = 5;
  const route = buildRoute(API_ROUTES.GET_JOBS, `per_page=${numberOfResults}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    httpService
      .get<JobHome[]>(route)
      .then(async (res) => {
        if (!res.response) {
          dispatch({
            type: ActionType.FAIL,
            error: {
              message: getReasonPhrase(res.status),
              code: res.status,
            },
          });
          return;
        }
        dispatch({
          type: ActionType.SUCCESS,
          result: res.response,
        });
      })
      .catch((_) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ActionType.FAIL,
          error: {
            code: StatusCodes.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
            message: getReasonPhrase(StatusCodes.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE),
          },
        });
      });
  }, [httpService, route]);
  return jobs;
};
```

The test:

```
describe('[Hook] useJobs', () => {
  const httpServiceInstance = new HttpService();
  it.only('Should return jobs when response is successful', async () => {
    const response: IApiResponse<Job[]> = {
      status: 200,
      response: [mockJob()],
    };

    jest
      .spyOn(httpServiceInstance, 'get')
      .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(response));

    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => (
      <HttpContext.Provider value={httpServiceInstance}>
        {children}
      </HttpContext.Provider>
    );
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useJobs(), {
      wrapper,
    });

    await waitForNextUpdate();
    
    expect(result.current).toEqual([mockJob()]);
  });
});
```

The warning:

```
Warning: An update to TestHook inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at TestHook (/{}/node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks/lib/index.js:21:23)
        at Suspense
        at wrapper (/{}/hooks/useJobs.spec.tsx:23:22)

      29 |           return;
      30 |         }
    > 31 |         dispatch({
         |         ^
      32 |           type: ActionType.SUCCESS,
      33 |           result: res.response,
      34 |         });
```

Thank you all very much

Comment: Hi. Did you figure out this? @Lux